# Install Gnome without extras and Ubuntu-Session

Tags: gnome, software-installation, 17.10, gnome-shell

I am running Ubuntu Studio 17.10 and would love to install Gnome to use alongside Xfce.

I tried running 'sudo apt install gnome', which did install Gnome but it also installed the Canonical Ubuntu version of gnome as well as changing my display manager to their version of GDM which is not what I wanted.

I also attempted to purge the Ubuntu-session however this lead to an incredibly unstable system and I resorted to reinstalling Ubuntu Studio.

Is there such thing as a minimal Gnome install, which allows me to simply install a single gnome session with only its bare essential components and nothing else?

Thank you in advance :)

Comment: Try `sudo apt install vanilla-gnome-desktop`.

Comment: No dice unfortunately, it still installed and configured GDM and the Ubuntu session.

Answer (score 1):

I have had the best results using:

```
sudo apt install gnome-session --no-install-recommends
```

Then just installing anything else I need once I'm in Gnome.